# And now I'm in your head

Tags: vocabulary

Gwenny: Hello Alexa.

Alexa:  Hello Gwenny.

Gwenny: Long time

Alexa:  Not Long enough

Gwenny: Sorry you didn't make the basketball team.

Alexa:  What? School has not even started.

Gwenny:  **And now I'm in your head**

Alexa:   Well, I'm in your head and there is an echo because there is nothing else in here with me.

Gwenny: Cause everything left when you walked in.

Alexa: Maybe I'll redecorated all in here

-Don't you dare.

-too late it's done.

*Movie: Alexa and Katie.*

What does the bold part mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two characters seem to be enemies. "Now I'm in your head" probably just means "Now you're thinking about me" or perhaps "Now you're thinking, and worrying, about the basketball team."  Either way, it is a minor piece of teenage girl nastiness implying "I have manipulated you". The expression could indicate "I know what you're thinking about".